# rewrite just the / root directory to a specific page

Tags: wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a wordpress site, and I'm trying to change just the homepage. Meaning, when people get to www.example.com they will be redirected to www.example.com/page.html . all other requests should go where they usually go - a wordpress permalink.

tried this, but it doesn't work. all requests go to page.html

```
RewriteRule /$ http://www.example.com/page.html$1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ruler for your index page, not for redirecting itself:

```
  DirectoryIndex page.html
```